# How can I get php to display the entire content of my file?

Tags: php

I have a text file :
Topic identified: Sports

I have 2 php files:

file 1:

```
<?php
    include "topic_detection.php";  
    $text = isset($_POST["text"]) ? $_POST["text"] : '';

    $file = "textfile.txt";
    $outputfile= "outputfile.txt";


    if(!empty($_POST)){
    writetofile($file, $text, "w");
    execpython($file);

    $topic = getoutput($outputfile);
    }

?>
```

file 2: topic_detection.php

```
<?php
function writetofile($file, $content, $writeType){
    $fo = fopen($file, $writeType);
    if($fo){
        fwrite($fo,$content);
        fclose($fo);
    }   
}

function execpython($file){
    system("python predict.py $file");

}

function getoutput($file1){
$fh= fopen($file1, 'r');
$theData = fread($fh,1);
fclose($fh);
echo $theData;
return $theData;
}
?>
```

On trying to get the output of `$theData`, the only output I receive is a `'T'` I am guessing this T is coming from the first letter in the text file. In that case, am I not making the call correctly?

here is my call:

```
<div align="center"><h4 style="line-height:150%;"><?php echo $topic; ?></h5></div>
```

Comment: Correct, you're only getting the first letter of the file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Comment: Can't you just use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)? You're not appending anything and you're not reading a huge file that requires buffering.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `fread` a length of 1:
`$theData = fread($fh,1);`

You will always get only the first character.

To read the entire file: (From the PHP docs http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

`$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));`

You could also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php